# Mongodb aggregation response

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Property controller :

```
//Get Properties By Type
const getPropertiesByType = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { cities, type } = req.query
    const citiesArr = typeof cities === 'string' ? cities.split(',') : []
    try {
        const property = await Promise.all(
            citiesArr?.map((item) => {
                return PropertyModel.aggregate([
                    {
                        $match: { city: item, propertyType: type },
                    },
                    {
                        $project: {
                            _id: 0,
                            city: 1,
                            country: 1,
                            cityPhoto: 1,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        $group: {
                            _id: '$city',
                            country: { $first: '$country' },
                            totalProperties: { $sum: 1 },
                            cityPhoto: { $first: '$cityPhoto' },
                        },
                    },
                ])
            })
        )
        res.status(201).json(property)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(400).json(error)
    }
}
```

in Postman i am getting this reponse :

```
[
    [
        {
            "_id": "Davenport",
            "country": "United States",
            "totalProperties": 1,
            "cityPhoto": "https://"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "_id": "Destin",
            "country": "United States",
            "totalProperties": 1,
            "cityPhoto": "https://"
        }
    ],
]
```

Problem is, that i get all objects in arrays, but i want instead get in response all objects in one main array. Also, can i do that without aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) once you receive aggregation result:

```js
const property = [
    [
        {
            "_id": "Davenport",
            "country": "United States",
            "totalProperties": 1,
            "cityPhoto": "https://"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "_id": "Destin",
            "country": "United States",
            "totalProperties": 1,
            "cityPhoto": "https://"
        }
    ],
] ; // your aggregation output

const response = property.flatMap(x => x);
console.log(response);
```

The reason you can't do it directly in aggregation pipeline is you are using `Promise.all` which returns an array and each `.aggregate()` also returns an array so you will get an array of arrays anyway.

Comment: OK, it works for me, Thank you!. I thought that i have to solve this problem using some aggregation method.

Comment: Actually can i solve this using aggregation methods?

Comment: @Eric modified my answer and added an explanation why it has to be done this way

Answer (score 0):

Looks like @mickl provided an answer as to how to the structure of the response via `flatMap()` after the database finishes its processing. Seems like a perfectly acceptable approach. But to the question in the comments about doing it via aggregation, I think there is an alternative that I explore below.

If I am reading the code correctly, you are taking a look at the `cities` query parameter and expecting a string that contains a comma delimited list of values.  Something like `"A,B,C"`. After splitting that into an array of individual values (contained in `citiesArr`), you then issue an individual `aggregate()` request to the database for each entry in that array (via the `map` where each city is now an `item`).

I think you can, and probably should, collapse this into a single call to the database. In terms of the aggregation itself, it would require changing

```
                    {
                        $match: { city: item, propertyType: type },
                    }
```

To something like

```
                    {
                        $match: { city: { $in: citiesArr }, propertyType: type },
                    }
```

If you similarly change the structure of the code surrounding this database call (e.g. no need for the `.all()` and `.map()`) then I think the direct response from the database will be more along the lines of what you are looking for.

Two additional things come to mind:

1. The `$project` stage that you have in the middle isn't valuable. The database will figure out what stages you need for the `$group` and retrieve just those automatically. I'd recommend removing the `$project` entirely to simplify things.
2. With this approach I'd still suggest checking that `citiesArr` is nonempty before issuing the aggregation. There is no need for a roundtrip to the database if the array is empty and therefore no results can be returned.